# Detect Lost Connection In Publish And Change Host RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I develop a very simple app using RabbitMQ. One machine, multiple queues and exchanges, one publisher and one consumer. After reading further about [Clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and [HA](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) I connect a second machine to create a cluster, besides I mirrored queues to have at least one replica. Now when I want to publish some data into a queue, I use the first machine as my host and it works fine, but if RabbitMQ service of the first machine not running my app crashed. 
My question is how to know which machine is up for creating connection and how to change the host while publishing messages?
**UPDATE**
I use one of `CreateConnection` overloads to pass all my hosts for creating a connection. OK, this will solve the problem of finding an available machine to create a connection. But the second question is still there, look at the code below:

```
for(int i = 0, i < 300, i++){
    var message = string.Format("Message #{0}: {1}", i, Guid.NewGuid());
    var messageBodyTypes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    channel.BasicPublish(ExchangeName, "123456", null, messageBodyBytes);
}
```

These lines of code is work perfect when the connection is OK, but assume that in the middle of publishing messages to an exchange, the service stopped unexpectedly, then in this case first `System.IO.FileLoadException` raised and if I continue the executation `RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException` raised which is saying:

> Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=320, text="CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'", classId=0, methidId=0, cause=

I think there must be a way to change the host when the connection closed during publishing messages, but how, no IDEA!

Answer (score 0):

> These lines of code is work perfect when the connection is OK, but
> assume that in the middle of publishing messages to an exchange, the
> service stopped unexpectedly, then in this case first
> System.IO.FileLoadException raised and if I continue the executation
> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException raised which is
> saying:

You must close the channel and current connection and open a new one of each mid-loop. That should use a different connection. You only have to do this when the exception is caught, not on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: No, I mean that when you catch the `AlreadyClosedException` you should close the current channel and connection and re-open a new connection and channel from the connection factory. You only have to do this when an exception is thrown.